# select SQL query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a three tables

table 1 - key columns `p1,  p2`
table 2 - key columns  `p1, STATUS`
table 3 - key columns `p2, STATUS`

In table 1, if p1 is 0, then p2 will have value. but not the vice versa. 
If p1 is there, then I need to check status in table 2, if not I need to check the status in table 3.

Now I need select find count of rows which are having pending status in any of table 2 and 3 from table 1.

Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: I would ask about the data structure - seems a little odd. What are you using it for?

Comment: table 1 has two childs, table 2 and 3. when you create row for today, it will go to table 2. if you schedule a row for table 2, you will get entry in table 3. when the scheduled day comes, table 2 will have data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE p1 WHEN 0 THEN t2.status ELSE t3.status END
FROM    t1
LEFT JOIN
        t2
ON      t2.p1 = p1
LEFT JOIN
        t3
ON      t1.p1 = 0
        AND t3.p2 = t1.p2
```